# Sending Eddystone UID packet via hcitool

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibeacon, beacon, eddystone, eddystone-url

I'm trying to send Eddystone UID packets with my hcitool but I cannot find it via my BLE scanner(I can find another Eddystone UID beacons around with my BLE scanner and also I can find my Eddystone URLthat has been sent with my hcitool). my command: sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 06 03 03 aa fe 15 16 aa fe 00 e7 43 f2 ac d1 4a 82 8e a1 2c 30 11 11 11 11 11 11 could you let me know if I'm wrong about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the final RFU bytes at the end of the UID so the command should be

sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1f 02 01 06 03 03 aa fe 17 16 aa fe 00 e7 43 f2 ac d1 4a 82 8e a1 2c 30 11 11 11 11 11 11 00 00